# How to start a job every day at the same hour in Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduling, quartz.net

I have to execute job every day at midnight Pacific Time. I am using MVC3 with Quartz.NET library.

Here is my code:

```
public static void ConfigureQuartzJobs()
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

    DateTime dateInDestinationTimeZone = System.TimeZoneInfo
        .ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, System.TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id, "Pacific Standard Time").Date;


    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TimeJob>()
        .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .StartAt(dateInDestinationTimeZone)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    sched.Start();
}
```

This code makes this job run only once at first midnight(in Pacific Time). I have set there `.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever())` but it is not working - job is not repeating every day.

What can I do to make it work every day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are your scheduled tasks hosted by web application? If so, you may experience such problems. Web applications are not suitable for running scheduled tasks. You should rather create windows service that hosts scheduled tasks.

But there are also some things you may check:

1. Try using shorter period of time (i.e. check if this works if you set interval to 1 minute).
2. Try [CronTrigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html) - i'm using it in windows service and it works fine.

There are some articles that explain what are pros and cons of hosting scheduled tasks in web application, ie. this one: http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/running-a-scheduled-task/.

Comment: I used CronTrigger - it is not working perfectly. It runs not exactly when it should, but close enough.

Comment: In my case, reducing the time interval from 30 minutes to 5 minutes makes the job work properly.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked 7 years ago  and there is already accepted reply. But i think throughout 7 years there  has been a little bit changes so i would suggest  this solution via **CronScheduleBuilder**.

```
        //Constructing job trigger.
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                          .WithIdentity("Test")
                          .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                          .DailyAtHourAndMinute(16,40))
                      .WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x.WithIntervalInMinutes(number)
                          .WithRepeatCount(number) 
                          .Build();
```

This code trigger job every day at particular time in this case 16:40. With interval *number* times and repeat count with *number* times